Visual Studio 2022 is very slow when I run code if my device is connected to internet
I'm a student and currently learning C++ so I use VS2022.
Codes used to run perfectly normal, but suddenly, whenever I run the code, it started taking almost 22 seconds for the code to run, even if it was a simple "Hello World!"
However, if I don't have an Internet connection, it runs perfectly normal!
Any ideas on how to fix this?
I've tried installing and reinstalling VS2022 and still the same happened. Someone told me to turn off any new extensions I installed but I never installed any to begin with.

My first thought is "antivirus software"..

Open the task manager when you compile, check which process drain your cpu.

@cpprust Changing everyhting on a system with a problem is not very likely to solve to underlying issue. So that's bad (debugging) advice. Anyway on SO you shouldn't even bother to answer/comment on low quality questions like this.
